# Why is the expression $(((30 / 2) / 2) / 2)$ same as $30 / 2^3$

Tags: arithmetic

Why is the expression $$(((30 / 2) / 2) / 2)$$ same as $$30 / 2^3$$

Comment: A parenthesis is missing?

Comment: Yes! It is correct

Comment: $30/2=15$, $15/2=7.5$, $7.5/2=3.75$. Then $30/2^3=30/8=3.75$.

Comment: The expressions are not the same, the result of their evaluation is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align} \color{blue}{(30/2)/2} &= \frac{30}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\\ 
&=\color{teal}{ \frac{30}{2^2}}
\end{align}.$$

Hence
$$\begin{align}
(\color{blue}{(30/2)/2})/2 &= \color{teal}{\left(\frac{30}{2^2}\right)}\bigg{/}2\\
&= \frac{30}{2^2}\times \frac{1}{2}\\
&= \frac{30}{2^3}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Recall:

$(30/2)=30\cdot \dfrac{1}{2};$

$((30/2)/2)=(30\cdot \dfrac{1}{2})\cdot \dfrac{1}{2};$

$(30/2)/2)/2=$

$((30 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2})\cdot \dfrac{1}{2})\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}= 30 \cdot (\dfrac{1}{2})^3= \dfrac{30}{2^3}$

Used: Associative law of multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

$$30\div2\div2\div2=\frac{30}{2}\div2\div2$$
$$=\frac{30}{2^2}\div2$$
$$=\frac{30}{2^3}$$

Comment: Looking at this as a multiplication by a fraction is the only way to prove it?